How can I calculate the subtotals of a pivot table in Pandas like in Excel?
I've data like this:
data = {
    'nomenclature': ['Display_product', 'Display_product', 'Decorative_textile', 'Decorative_textile', 'Children_clothing', 'Children_clothing', 'Children_textile', 'Children_textile', 'Home_textile', 'Home_textile'],
    'city': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'sales_2022': [4249.83, 7676.52, 428591.60, 580723.77, 2384600.57, 1878142.39, 316407.44, 309485.86, 10419592.44, 9594930.55],
    'sales_2023': [39376.59, 32938.23, 287329.79, 470398.06, 2663005.41, 2253031.33, 333918.23, 312715.71, 10963845.16, 9967580.97]
}

Want to create a pivot table grouped by nomenclature with subtotals
